# Angular Code Question - Inject data into mat-dialog-actions

Tags: angular, inject, mat-dialog

I need to get some data to a method in Angular. Here is the code:

I need to get data into addNpi() just like editNpi(data) below

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

```
<mat-dialog-content>
  <ip-data-table
    [columnData]="columnData"
    [data]="data"
    [actionTemplate]="npiActions"
  ></ip-data-table>
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
  <ip-show-obsolete
    [disabled]="false"
    [clearCheckbox]="clearCheckbox"
    (showObsolete)="showObsolete($event)"
  >
    <button class="mr-2" mat-button (click)="addNpi()">Add</button>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
  </ip-show-obsolete>
</mat-dialog-actions>

<ng-template #npiActions let-data="data">
  <button type="button" [disabled]="!data.active" mat-menu-item (click)="editNpi(data)">
    Edit
  </button>
  <button type="button" [disabled]="!data.active" mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
</ng-template>​
```

Comment: Does `(click)="addNpi(data)"` not work for some reason?

Comment: Thanks for replying, when I try that, data does not make it into the method. So I think I need to make it available in the scope of mat-dialog-actions, at least that is what I think. You can tell my Angular knowledge is limited.

Comment: Well, I tried it one more time, data gets an undefined error. I think I need something like let-data="data" somewhere in mat-dialog-actions. These buttons, Add/Close and Edit/Remove are separated into different dialogs because of their function on the web page.

Comment: I actually didn't write this code, I am just trying to change an error in the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the contractor who wrote the code helped me out. As it turns out, I can refer to the variable 'data' in many places. So in the addNpi() method, we put this statement:

const rowData = this.data.find(item => item.active);

This made the 'data' available in the rowData variable.

Then this code:

const dialogData = {

```
  transType: 'I',

  npiData: rowData,

};
```

dialogData was already being created and we added rowData as a variable named npiData. Then when the new dialog appeared, I was able to access npiData and all was well.